# Proving that Turing decidable languages are closed under reversal

Tags: turing-machines

I need to prove that Turing decidable languages are closed under reversal. I have no idea on how I would prove this. Any suggestions or clues?

Comment: Turing machines have an _infinitely long_ tape, is there some way given an input word w, you could obtain the word in reverse order?

Comment: Yes. Move to the last character of the string, place a dollar sign after it, go back and write the characters from the last to the first one and replace the original string with blanks.

Comment: The dollar sign would of course also be erased at the end. (Used the dollar sign simpluy to separate the original and reversed string).

Comment: Now notice that reversing a word _twice_ recovers the original word. Then can we use the decider for a language L to determine if a word is the reverse of a word in L?

Comment: Also note that formally we must determine if the reversed word is in L _or not_ which I neglected to say in my previous comment. This is not an issue since we assume we have a decider for L.

Comment: So, we assumed we have a decider for L. If the reverse of a string x is in L then, we have no problem. Otherwise, I didn't quite understand what you were trying to say.

Comment: I mean, we didnt assume, its given to us. But yeah.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/136703/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4062904/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).  Also, it is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4059727/14578.  Please do more searching and research before asking in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Let $L$ be a decidable language and let $M$ be a decider for $L$. Since $M$ *decides* $L$, $M$ always halts and accepts if its input is in $L$ and rejects if its input is not in $L$.

We know that string reversal can be performed by a Turing machine. Let's construct a Turing machine to *decide* if a word is in $L^r=\{w=w_0w_1...w_n \mid w^r=w_nw_{n-1}...w_0\in L\}$.

Let $M'$ = "On input $w$ 
$\quad$reverse the string $w$ to obtain $w^r$ 
$\quad$run $M$ on $w^r$ 
$\quad$if $M$ accepts, $ACCEPT$ 
$\quad$otherwise, $REJECT$ "

Then $M'$ accepts $w$ if and only if $M$ accepts $w$. Since $M$ is a decider, both machines always halt. Then $M'$ decides $L^r$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you have a Turing machine $M$ that accepts a language $L$.

Construct a new Turing machine which, on input $x$, reverses its input and then passes control to $M$. The new Turing machine accepts the reverse of $L$.